# Jquery to handle special characters returned on server-side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, special-characters

For example, ñ is stored in my database as &#241.

I want my .ASPX page to display them as they should be, which is ñ. Niño cannot be displayed as Ni&#241o.

I believe I can do this in ASP.NET (I think I have to put something like ValidateRequest=false to each databound item?), but I was wondering if there's a way I can do this with Jquery?

Comment: What kind of control are you databinding to? DataGrid? Gridview? DropDownList?

Comment: GridView and ListView, using <%# Eval("Item") %>

Comment: Ok i believe I can just do <asp:Label id="Item1" text='<%#Eval("Item")%>' HtmlEncode="false" />. But is there a way to do it in Jquery/Client-side?

Answer (score 0):

For the GridView, assuming it's a `BoundColumn`, just set the `HTMLEncode` property to `False` for that column (`<asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" HeaderText="Field 1" HtmlEncode="False" />`).

For the ListView (or for a templated GridView), you can use `<%# Server.HTMLDecode(Eval("Item")) %>`.

To do this all client-side in jQuery (assuming you are using an `<asp:Label />` in the ListView):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> td, #<%=ListView1.ClientID %> span').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var decodedText = unescape($this.text());
        $this.text(decodedText);
    });
});
```